# Whats the best practise for using variables in many different classes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, static, global-variables

Lets say a User in my App can note his weight. Now I want to use this weight in many other Widgets all over my App for example to calculate some data, which depends on the user weight.

Is it a good practise to use a static variable like this:

```
class UserManager {
  static double weight;
}
```

So now I have access to the User weight in every Class and can make calculations for example:

```
double value = UserManager.weight * 0.4;
```

Is this a good practise or are there some better solutions?

Comment: A `static` variable is the equivalent of a global variable.  It makes sense only if there will ever be only one value shared throughout your application.  It makes no sense if you have multiple `User`s who each might have different weights.  If you have only a single `User`, you might as well make it an instance variable on that and make the `User` object a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GetStorage()

```
final appData = GetStorage();
appData.writeIfNull("data", false);
bool yourVar = appData.read("data");
```

or SharedPreferences

```
var yourData;
final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  void _getSomeTh() async {
    final prefs = await _prefs;
    final result = prefs.getBool("data");
   yourData = result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better not to work with static variables, but to have an object that you distribute to all widgets in the widget tree. You can achieve this, for example, with an `InheritedWidget` or with packages such as `BLoC` or `Provider`. Making such data static seems to me to be an anti-pattern.

With the BLoC pattern:

```
class User {
  final double weight;

  User({required this.weight});
}

class UserManager extends Cubit<User>{
   ...
}
```

This way you have a state managing system with which you could very easily rebuild all the widgets concerned when the weight changes.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple requirement as this, the `static variable` approach might be fine. However, for a more complex object that you wish to share in a hierarchy of widgets, you should use packages like [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

For example, you have a `User` object that you wish to share app-wide, then

```
class User with ChangeNotifier {
  late String uuid;
  late String name;
  // Our one and only one static instance on which we operate
  static late User? instance;
  // There is a good chance that the init functions like below are async too
  static void initUser(String uuid, String name) {
    instance = User._init(uuid, name);
  }
  
  // It is usually the 'instance' that calls the below function
  void changeFunction(/*params*/){
    // Change the user instance, say, assign it to null if a user logs out
    // More importanly, notify the listeners about the change
    notifyListeners();
  }
  
  // Note this constructor is not exposed to the public.
  User._init(this.uuid,this.name);
}
```

Then propagate the `User` object using a `ChangeNotifierProvider` using the guidelines mentioned [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html)

Comment: What is the advantage of this Solution? For me it looks like more code and more complex structure. What is wrong with just using a static variable?

Comment: If you wish to notify child widgets, say rebuild them on value changes, then you need this approach. The best example would be a `User` object. Show login screen when the user is not logged in. Else, show the home screen.

Comment: Okay thank you, but does using static variables have any disadvantage except this?

Comment: Using `static` variables also means that your data is not persistent. Should you need data persistency, you should use packages like `SharedPreferences` which is a platform-independent solution for data persistence.